# 'join' not woking in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my users model:

```
id | name | user_Zip
1  | abc  | 10005
2  | mno  | 10005
3  | ijk  | 10005
```

And, In my professions model:

```
id | UserID | Designation
1  | 1      | Lead
2  | 2      | Lead
3  | 3      | Software Engineer
```

`UserID` is the foreign_key. In my search text-box I am enter "user_Zip", i.e 10005, then I want it to give me a name and a designation of users whose `user_Zip = 10005`.

I am using this code:

```
def search
    if ( !params[:tf_Zip].blank? or params[:tf_Zip] != "" )
       @user_zip = User.find(:all,:conditions=>['"user_Zip" = ? ',params[:tf_Zip]])
        end
end
```

This works fine, but it doess not give me the designation of the user.

When I use this code with join:

```
def search
  if ( !params[:tf_Zip].blank? or params[:tf_Zip] != "" )
    @user_zip = Profession.joins(:user).where('users.user_Zip' => params[:tf_Zip]) 
  end
end
```

It also works fine, but does not give me the required result.

These are the models:

```
# user's model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :professions, dependent: :destroy
end

# profession's model
class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :UserID
    validates :UserID, presence: true
end
```

As you can see above, I set foreign_key `UserID` but it gave me `"progession"."user_id" = ?` and it makes by default foreign_key `user_id`

Comment: and what is your required result? You're going to get back an ActiveRecord::Relation of Profession objects.

Comment: what is meaning by required result, I think that I would be returning array of profession object that have associated user object.

Comment: When I run this query {Select First_Name,Last_Name,Designation,user_Zip from users inner join professions on
 users.id=professions.UserID where user_Zip=10005} in sqllite then it give me only 3 results but in the post its not give me the same result as this.

Comment: Your foreign keys are not correct - let me write some suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

**Schemas**

```
#users
id | name | profession_id | zip
1  | abc  | 1             | 10005
2  | mno  | 1             | 10005
3  | ijk  | 2             | 10005

#professions
id | designation
1  | Lead
2  | Software Engineer
```

---

**Models**

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :profession
end

#app/models/profession.rb
Class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end
```

---

**Actions**

```
def search
    zip = params[:tf_Zip]
    unless zip && zip.blank?
       @users = User.where(zip: zip) #-> returns User records for SQL
    end
end

@users.each do |user|
    user.profession.designation #-> outputs "Lead" / "Software Engineer" for each user
end
```

Comment: Unneded parens in condition. Also `String#blank?` check for empty string, so the second test is unneded. It should rather check for `nil` instead.

Comment: Yes was going to do that, thanks for update. I was working on fixing his code more than getting details 100% right. I'll refactor for you

Comment: Blank checks for nil, too, but present? is the most communicative here. But no, this isn't what you want, because it will continue to query the database in the loop. Joins exist for a reason.

Comment: Thanks Dave - I hope it helps the OP out

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add more on answer given by Rich

**Models**

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profession

  def self.search keyword
    return [] if keyword.blank?
    self.includes(:profession).where(zip: keyword.strip)
  end
end

#app/models/profession.rb
class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end
```

**Action**

```
def search
    @users = User.search params[:tf_Zip]
end
```

**View**

```
@users.each do |user|
    user.profession.designation
end
```

In this way it will fire only two queries.

------------------- OR -------------------

if you strictly wants join(1 single query) then you can write it as follows

**Models**

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profession

  def self.search keyword
    return [] if keyword.blank?
    self.join(:profession).where(zip: keyword.strip).select("users.*, professions.name")
  end
end

#app/models/profession.rb
Class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end
```

**Action**

```
def search
    @users = User.search params[:tf_Zip]
end
```

**View**

```
@users.each do |user|
    user['designation']
end
```